# How do I change has_many and belongs_to to has_many and has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a user-model and a schedule-model.
First I wanted to have many schedules which belongs_to one user.
Now I want to have many schedules which has/belongs_to many users.

Here are my code-snippets:

**user-model:**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'bcrypt'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  has_many :schedules
  [...]
end
```

**schedule-model:**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  [...]
end
```

The Database attributes are:
**user-model:**
there is no attribute for schedule.
**schedule-model:**
user_id as integer

**How can I change it correctly?**

---

**EDIT:**
generated-output:

```
class CreateUsersSchedulesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :schedules do |t|
      # t.index [:user_id, :schedule_id]
      # t.index [:schedule_id, :user_id]
    end
  end
end

class RemoveUserIdFromSchedule2 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :schedules, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

**SQL:**

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-29 16:05:25 +0200
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1
Schedule Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" INNER JOIN "schedules_users" ON "schedules"."id" = "schedules_users"."schedule_id" WHERE "schedules_users"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "schedules"."date_time" ASC  [["user_id", 12]]
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 44.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

The migration works fine. There is a new table with the ids, now, but I have to change the controller as well, because my order-method didnt work atm. Can anyone/you help me ?

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if(current_user)
      @user_schedules = current_user.schedules
      @user_schedules_date = @user_schedules.order(:date_time).group_by { |sched| sched.date_time.beginning_of_day }
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a join table, you probably want to name the new table : 'users_schedules', this new table should contains two columns : user_id and schedule_id (use a migration):

```
class CreateUsersSchedulesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users_schedules, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :schedule_id
    end
  end
end
```

And another to remove the old columns in the previous table :

```
class RemoveUserIdColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        remove_column :schedule, :user_id
    end
end
```

Then update your model to be like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :schedules
    .....
end
```

and

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    .....
end
```

This should work !

Comment: Awesome. I'll try it in some minutes and tell you whether I failed or not :D. Thanks.

Comment: `rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserSchedule user schedule` is that the correct rails command ?

Comment: The columns should contains _id, so I think it would look like `rails g migration CreateJoinTableUsersSchedules user_id:integer schedule_id:integer`

Comment: No it isn't. I tried this now: `rails g migration CreateUsers
SchedulesJoinTable user_id:integer schedule_id:integer`, but there is no schedule_id in the schedule_model, so that I schould add?

Comment: There is no schedule_id but there is an id and ActiveRecord use the format "modelname_id" to identify an object. Could you give the output of the generated migration

Comment: There is a schedule_id.. I forgot that ror add this automatically. Ok it works fine, but.. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Could you give us the output of the rails server when making the request (the generated SQL or the error if any)

Comment: Sure. Sorry for that missunderstanding. I put it into the question. :)